# Is there a way I can update user profile(details) in postgres and node js witbout having to send all parameters in the request body everytime?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, express

I have a postgres query in this format: 
UPDATE farmers SET first_name=$1, last_name=$2, contact_no=$3, cooperative_name=$4 WHERE verification_id=$5

However, this will require me to send all for parameters in the request body whenever I want to update the data, else I will get a null value for parameter not included.

Is there a way I can write this either in node js or postgres or both such that I only include the parameter(s) I want to update in the request body without setting the other values to null.

[this is my services where I am using the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AndDn.png)

Comment: Please **do not post images**. However you can do what your asking; you just have to generate a ifferent sql statement each time to only include those items which you have. Which of course would be more and more difficult code. If you have the data values available then clearest, cleanest, and simplest process is just pass them all each time - i.e. the best process is what you are trying to eliminate. Note. It makes no difference if you send the same existing value the entire row is rewritten each time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem sometime back and I created a function to do just that.

```js
const addComma = (len) => len > 1 ? ', ' : '';

/**
 * @param {updateStmtObject} {table, fields, condition}
 * @returns {string} query
 */
function createUpdateStatement(table, fields, condition){
    let query = {
        text: `UPDATE ${table} SET`,
        values: []
    }

    Object.keys(fields).forEach(col => {
        query.values.push(fields[col]);
        query.text += `${addComma(query.values.length)} ${col} = $${query.values.length}`;      
    });

    if (query.values.length > 0) {
        if(condition){
            const col = Object.keys(condition)[0];
            query.values.push(condition[col]);
            query.text += ` WHERE ${col} = $${query.values.length}`;
        }

        return query;
    } else {
        //No changes to be made
        return null;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    createUpdateStatement
};



/**
 * Update statement object
 * @typedef {Object} updateStmtObject
 * @property {string} table - Table to be updated
 * @property {object} fields - An object of column_name:value pairs for the query
 * @property {object} condition - column_name:value pair for update condition.
 *   Only single condition currently supported. Add other conditions manually.
 */
```

Just copy and paste it into a util.js file or whatever then you can call it like so to dynamically generate an UPDATE statement:

```js
const { createUpdateStatement } = require('util.js');

const updateData = {first_name: 'Benz', last_name: 'Stevox'};
const query = createUpdateStatement('users', updateData, {verification_id: 5});
console.log(query);
/* 
{
  text: 'UPDATE users SET first_name = $1,  last_name = $2 WHERE verification_id = $3',
  values: [ 'Benz', 'Stevox', 5 ]
}
*/
```

It probably won't hold up for complex queries but simple statements like in your example should work out just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Benz Stevox. I will. try this

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is happening here? 
query.text += ` WHERE ${col} = $${query.values.length}`;
What is the function of the $$ operator

Comment: The ```${var}``` is used to insert a variable into a template string. So in this case, assuming the value of col is 'userId' and the length of the query.values array is 3, the resulting string will be "WHERE userId" = $3"

The first $ sign is a literal dollar sign, not an operator..

Comment: Thanks alot Benz. Do you have an idea how I can go about this:
I have a some data coming from the database, lets call it a cooperatives table which has state, area council and ward name columns. I am trying to write. a dynamic query for the table to filter by the parameters indicated. eg I can try to filter all data by a particular state

Comment: Do you mean like a SELECT statement with a dynamic WHERE condition? I'm not sure I understand your question clearly..

Comment: Thanks, don't bother I was able to figure that out